# Two types of one-to-many relations

Tags: relational-theory

first time poster here, and happy 2023!

When talking about different types of entities relationships, I tend to think the following three:

- one-to-one
- one-to-many / many-to-one
- many-to-many

However, I do know that the Crow's foot notation has splitted the one-to-many into two types:

[image]

I.e., the

- *"CUSTOMER places ORDER"* can have ***zero*** or many, but
- *"ORDER contains LINE-ITEM"* must have ***one*** to many

I know it is more accurate but I never thought further on the implications to the DDL and DML level. So,

What's the impact of these two types of one-to-many relations at DDL and DML level please? For e.g.,

if I do or don't tell them part, then what differences are when it comes to defining the relations in DDL; and the restrains when doing DML. What would I gain or be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no natural, first-class way to model a 1-to-(One or Many) in an RDBMS.

You could model this by adding a foreign key on SalesOrder pointing to some LineItem, but in practice this is very rarely done.

You model all 1-1, 1-many, 1-zero or one, and 1-one to many using a foreign key.

There is an important DDL-affecting difference between these relationships, but it's not captured in the notation you're using.  The relationship between Order and customer is a weak relationship, because you could have an order with no customer, and Order and Customer are both "strong entities".  The relationship between Order and LineItem is strong, as you can't have a LineItem without an order, and LineItem is a "weak entity".

The impact on DDL is that strong containment-type relationships are canonically modeled by the many side foreign key being a subset of its key, and by using cascade deletes.

In SQL Server I would model this as

```
create table Customer
(
  CustomerNumber varchar(20) primary key,
  Name nvarchar(200),
  Sector varchar(20)
)

create table SalesOrder
(
  OrderNumber int identity primary key,
  CustomerNumber varchar(20) null references Customer on delete set null,
  DeliveryAddress nvarchar(200)
)


create table SalesOrderLineItem
(
  SalesOrderId int not null references SalesOrder on delete cascade,
  SalesOrderLineItemId int identity not null,
  Quantity int,
  PricePerUnit decimal(20,2),
  primary key (SalesOrderId,  SalesOrderLineItemId)
)
```